# How can I insert the child class' name as an argument in an inherited function?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have this code:

```
class Scene():
    def go_back():
        prev = map.get(child_class_name) # how do I insert child class' here?

class B(Scene):
    pass

class A(Scene)
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class A")

map = {
    "B": A()
    "C": B()
    "D": C()
    "U no": "de drill"
}

x = B()

x.go_back() # this should run class A()'s __init__
```

How can I access a child class in `Scene.go_back`?

Comment: To run the ```__init__``` of a class, you've to create a new object of that class

Comment: the __init__ part actually works for now, anyways I found the answer on discord, I'll share it soon here.

Comment: bruh, how do I tag some text as code in a comment

Comment: just surround them with " \`\`\` " like \`\`\`print('hello world')\`\`\` shows as ```print('hello world')```

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was insert `self` in there. But also there were a bunch of bugs in there. Here is the fixed code:

```
class Scene():
    def go_back(self):
        prev = map.get(self) # inserted self here

class B(Scene):
    pass

class A(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class A")

map = {
    "B": A(),
}

x = B()

x.go_back() # this should run class A()'s __init__
```